# how to config task to run/debug C# console app in vscode

Tags: console, visual-studio-code

from //build, i see the coolness of running nodejs and asp net 5
i am trying to use vscode to run some basic C# console app. how should i config the task to build and run/debug it? is there any sample?

Answer (score 10):

The yeoman aspnet generator has a ConsoleApplication template that will work in VSCode.

1. Install ASP.NET and DNX (according to your OS see the instructions here: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/ASPnet5)
2. Install yeoman dependencies and generate a yeoman aspnet project (choose Console Application)

   `npm install -g yo grunt-cli generator-aspnet bower`

   `yo aspnet`
3. cd to your project dir you just created and:

   `dnu restore`
4. Now you can open the dir in VSCode. Open the command palette (command-shift-P) and type `run`

**EDIT:**
Note however that while mono-based C# debugging works in Linux and OSX, ASP.NET 5 debugging does not yet work in the preview version.

Comment: A clarification: mono based C# debugging works on OS X and Linux in the preview version, but ASP.NET 5 debugging is not yet supported.

Comment: I've tried to follow the steps, if I run from terminal it works, if I run it from VSC it outputs an error