# dnx run a C# Console App on Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I've followed the steps [this guy proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29981210/3809894), but when I write "run" on VSC and select `dnx run`, it says:

> There are no entries to pick from
>   [image: vsc]

Here's the Omnisharp console output:

```
[INFO] Starting OmniSharp at '/Users/jonathan/Documents/UES/IAI/Projects/HelloWorld'...
[INFO] Started OmniSharp from '/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/ms-vscode.omnisharp/bin/omnisharp' with process id 524...
[INFORMATION:OmniSharp.Startup] Omnisharp server running using stdio at location '/Users/jonathan/Documents/UES/IAI/Projects/HelloWorld' on host 515.
[INFORMATION:OmniSharp.Dnx.DnxProjectSystem] No default runtime found
The specified runtime path 'default' does not exist. Searched locations /Users/jonathan/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-mono.1.0.0-rc1-update1
/Users/jonathan/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-mono.1.0.0-rc1-update1
/Users/jonathan/.dnx/packages/dnx-mono.1.0.0-rc1-update1
/Users/jonathan/.k/runtimes/dnx-mono.default
/Users/jonathan/.k/runtimes/kre-mono.default
/Users/jonathan/.k/packages/KRE-Mono.default
/Users/jonathan/.kre/runtimes/dnx-mono.default
/Users/jonathan/.kre/runtimes/kre-mono.default
/Users/jonathan/.kre/packages/KRE-Mono.default.
Visit https://github.com/aspnet/Home for an installation guide.

[INFORMATION:OmniSharp.MSBuild.MSBuildProjectSystem] No solution files found in '/Users/jonathan/Documents/UES/IAI/Projects/HelloWorld'
[INFORMATION:OmniSharp.ScriptCs.ScriptCsProjectSystem] Detecting CSX files in '/Users/jonathan/Documents/UES/IAI/Projects/HelloWorld'.
[INFORMATION:OmniSharp.ScriptCs.ScriptCsProjectSystem] Could not find any CSX files
[INFORMATION:OmniSharp.Startup] Solution has finished loading
[ERROR:OmniSharp.Dnx.DnxPaths] The specified runtime path 'default' does not exist. Searched locations /Users/jonathan/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-mono.1.0.0-rc1-update1
/Users/jonathan/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-mono.1.0.0-rc1-update1
/Users/jonathan/.dnx/packages/dnx-mono.1.0.0-rc1-update1
/Users/jonathan/.k/runtimes/dnx-mono.default
/Users/jonathan/.k/runtimes/kre-mono.default
/Users/jonathan/.k/packages/KRE-Mono.default
/Users/jonathan/.kre/runtimes/dnx-mono.default
/Users/jonathan/.kre/runtimes/kre-mono.default
/Users/jonathan/.kre/packages/KRE-Mono.default.
Visit https://github.com/aspnet/Home for an installation guide.
[INFORMATION:OmniSharp.Dnx.DnxProjectSystem] Scanning '/Users/jonathan/Documents/UES/IAI/Projects/HelloWorld' for DNX projects
[INFORMATION:OmniSharp.Dnx.DnxProjectSystem] Found project '/Users/jonathan/Documents/UES/IAI/Projects/HelloWorld/project.json'.
```

## UPDATE 1

**dnvm list -detailed**

```
Jonathans-MacBook-Pro:~ jonathan$ dnvm list -detailed

Active Version              Runtime Architecture OperatingSystem Alias Location
------ -------              ------- ------------ --------------- ----- --------
       1.0.0-rc1-update1    clr     x64          win                   /usr/local/lib/dnx/runtimes
       1.0.0-rc1-update1    clr     x86          win                   /usr/local/lib/dnx/runtimes
       1.0.0-rc1-update1    coreclr x64          darwin                /usr/local/lib/dnx/runtimes
       1.0.0-rc1-update1    coreclr x64          linux                 /usr/local/lib/dnx/runtimes
       1.0.0-rc1-update1    coreclr x64          win                   /usr/local/lib/dnx/runtimes
       1.0.0-rc1-update1    coreclr x86          win                   /usr/local/lib/dnx/runtimes
  *    1.0.0-rc1-update1    mono                 linux/osx       default /usr/local/lib/dnx/runtimes
```

Comment: Just get a Windows and use Visual Studio. I'm kidding :-) But just to compare: trying to run C# on OSX is like trying to run Objective-C on Windows :-)

Comment: It's just for a homework, I don't want to create a vm just for a console program, but yeah, I get your point @DarinDimitrov

Comment: @DarinDimitrov many universities do teach C# by using MonoDevelop on Linux. It is good enough for those exercises. Meanwhile, Objective C in Visual Studio is of course coming, https://dev.windows.com/en-us/bridges/ios

Comment: @LexLi, by *Objective-C on Windows*, I meant writing applications that will run on OSX and iOS devices using the Objective-C language under Windows. The link you have shown seems to point to some meaningless IMHO *bridge* that Microsoft have invented that would allow developers using the Objective-C programming language for writing Windows Universal applications that will run on the Windows platform. Which of course is quite different. I don't expect that people writing Objective-C code today would ever care about the Windows ecosystem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see full output from OmniSharp.log in this screenshot but 
I believe I had similar issue with running application in Visual Studio Code.
The problem is related with OmniSharp, which is looking for DNX runtimes in home directory: **$HOME/.dnx/runtimes**.
However, currently dnx runtimes are installed in **/usr/local/lib/dnx/runtimes**.
There are few possibilities how to solve it. I've used probably the easiest one: 
`ln -sfF /usr/local/lib/dnx/runtimes ~/.dnx/`

More information about this problem: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/126

You can also check where runtimes are located by using command:
**dnvm list -detailed**

My output looks like that (last column is important):

```
Active Version              Runtime Architecture OperatingSystem Alias   Location
------ -------              ------- ------------ --------------- -----   --------
       1.0.0-rc1-update1    coreclr x64          darwin          default /usr/local/lib/dnx/runtimes
       1.0.0-rc1-update1    mono                 linux/osx               /usr/local/lib/dnx/runtimes
```

Comment: Can you check your's runtime path with command: **dnvm list -detailed**. Last column (Location) is important here. From output, which you included, I'm sure that you have the same problem as I had. Can you also check if directory: **/Users/jonathan/.dnx/runtimes/** is empty?

Comment: Check the update in the question, and also **/Users/jonathan/.dnx/runtimes/** is empty

Comment: Everything looks like expected, omnisharp is searching dnx runtimes in folders:  
`/Users/jonathan/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-mono.1.0.0-rc1-update1, 
/Users/jonathan/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-mono.1.0.0-rc1-update1, 
/Users/jonathan/.dnx/packages/dnx-mono.1.0.0-rc1-update1`. 
However your dnx installation folder is: **/usr/local/lib/dnx/runtimes**.  
Can you run command `ln -sfF /usr/local/lib/dnx/runtimes ~/.dnx/` and check again in VSC?
This should help.